# T-SQL absence by month from start date end date

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-server-2000

I have an interesting query to do and am trying to find the best way to do it. Basically I have an absence table in our personnel database this records the staff id and then a start date and end date for the absence. End date being null if not yet entered (not returned). I cannot change the design.

They would like a report by month on number of absences (12 month trend). With staff being off over the month change it obviously may be difficult to calculate.

e.g. Staff off 25/11/08 to 05/12/08 (dd/MM/yy) I would want the days in November to go into the November count and the ones in December in the December count.

I am currently thinking in order to count the number of days I need to separate the start and end date into a record for each day of the absence, assigning it to the month it is in. then group the data for reporting. As for the ones without an end date I would assume null is the current date as they are presently still absent.

What would be the best way to do this?

Any better ways?

Edit: This is SQL 2000 server currently. Hoping for an upgrade soon.

Comment: Asking before starting, the way I can currently think of is joining to a table with all the dates in for the 12 months ON end_date >= date and start_date <= date. Think that would give a record for each date in the range. Hope that makes sense.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have had a similar issue where there has been a table of start/end dates designed for data storage but not for reporting.

I sought out the "fastest executing" solution and found that it was to create a 2nd table with the monthly values in there.  I populated it with the months from Jan 2000 to Jan 2070.  I'm expecting it will suffice or that I get a large pay cheque in 2070 to come and update it...

```
DECLARE TABLE months (start DATETIME)
-- Populate with all month start dates that may ever be needed
-- And I would recommend indexing / primary keying by start

SELECT
    months.start,
    data.id,
    SUM(CASE WHEN data.start < months.start
            THEN DATEDIFF(DAY, months.start, data.end)
            ELSE DATEDIFF(DAY, data.start, DATEADD(month, 1, months.start))
        END) AS days
FROM
    data
INNER JOIN
    months
        ON data.start < DATEADD(month, 1, months.start)
        AND data.end > months.start
GROUP BY
   months.start,
   data.id
```

That join can be quite slow for various reasons, I'll search out another answer to another question to show why and how to optimise the join.

EDIT:

Here is another answer relating to overlapping date ranges and how to speed up the joins...

[Query max number of simultaneous events](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/452499/query-max-number-of-simultaneous-events/453180#453180)

Comment: That's pretty much my current thought process joining to a table with a list of dates in, obviously I could maintain that with an overnight run or something or generate on the fly.

Comment: I did something similar to the date table, but I created a CLR UDF (this is with SQL Server) that would generate a table of dates.  Again assuming SQL Server, you could use common table expressions to do the same.

Comment: The overhead of having a table of dates/months is really low.  I would have it as a permanent table.  You get the benefits of the indexes then too.

Comment: Nah, it allows me to generate hour, day, week, month, or year ranges with whatever criteria I need and is lightning fast.

Comment: Still, having one or more permanent tables is always faster than generating them on the fly.  And in my case the indexing of the table made a difference...